# Where is chrome and other browser form and field data stored?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

It came as a surprise to me when I restarted my computer all the forms on Chrome were open with the text still intact? How is that possible. I thought the data is stored in RAM and would be deleted. When I restored the tabs, all the text in the forms and text boxes was there. This works in chrome and Firefox. This can have serious security implications if sensitive info is stored in such forms. How does one purge all browser data for good.

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers keep form history in a SQLite database file and not in RAM.
If you wish to avoid this, one way is to use in Chrome
an Incognito window and in Firefox a Private window.
In these modes, the data is only stored in RAM and is deleted once the
session is terminated.

You may also delete existing data or prevent it from being stored in the first
place as follows.

**Delete form data**

In Chrome form data can be manually erased using
*Settings > More tools > Clear browsing data....*.

In Firefox this is done in *Settings > Library > History > Clear Recent History…*.

**Disable form history**

In Chrome this is done via *Settings > Advanced > Autofill > Payment methods*,
disable "Save and fill payment methods".

In Firefox this is done in
Settings > Options > Privacy & Security*, and under *History* set
the drop-down menu to "Never remember history".